# Ethernet goes slower than WiFi and I need advices of what OTHER things to try

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet

*Little note before going into the problem: My main languague is spanish and I'm not used to writing in english, misspell is bound to happen.

Hi! Welcome to my question. The topics will be summarize like this:

1.- Problem Explanation

2.- What I have done so far

3.- Things I will do

**1. Problem Explanation**

Two days ago I've bought a new Ethernet cable cat 6 and found myself with good internet with no problems. Yesterday I found that the internet with the cable had irregularities (in downloading and uploading), but when i changed to WiFi I didn't had this problem. So I began doing tests.

**2. What I have done so far**

***Internet Test via this two websites:***

**WiFi:**

#Testmy.net

[Testmy.net_Wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX63V.png)

#Speedtest.net

[Speedtest.net_Wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgEIK.jpg)

**Ethernet:**

#Testmy.net

*It freezes up indefinitely

[Testmy.net_Ethernet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcgFk.png)

#Speedtest.net

*It freezes up indefinitely in upload

[Speedtest.net_Ethernet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1dfQ.png)

***Used another cable***

I have used another cable (cat5e) and have the same problem

***Network Reset***

Didn't help

***Change adapter options***

Disable/enable wifi/ethernet
Internet protocol reset

**3. Things I will do**

I will surely contact with my internet provider in seek of tecnical help. Outside of that, I don't have any other computer/laptop at the moment to do tests too.

Thanks for reading this thread

Comment: Trying a different cable was a good test. A few things that can slow down Ethernet: 1. A slower device, e.g. another PC, that has a slower speed forces *all* comms to be slower on that circuit. 2. Cable length approaching 100 m total. 3. Ethernet *port* on the router - try a different jack, if possible. 3. Router settings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @DrMoishePippik I'll try them right away

Comment: @DrMoishePippik #1 is false for both Ethernet and Wi-Fi. If you have, say, a gigabit Ethernet (10/100/1000) switch, connecting a 100 Mbit device to it does NOT keep the gigabit devices from talking to each other at gigabit speeds.

Comment: @Spiff, to quote Spiceworks: "You are only **limited by the speed of the slowest device communicating**, so if you're communicating with the printer, yes, you will run at 100MB..." https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/154017-network-speed-and-switch-simple-questions